# "Саша с Машей" или "Саша и Маша"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, как правильно: *Саша с Машей* или *Саша и Маша?*

Comment: Вы бы дали строчку из того самого текста с Машей, с Сашей. Или речь о названии?

Comment: Да нет никакого текста, вопрос просто в том, можно ли использовать "с" между двумя именами, или там должно быть "и". Саша с Машей шли по  дороге, например

Comment: Заглянем в букварь. ====  У ма-ши-ны. Са-ша с па-пой. Ма-ша с ма-мой. Ма-ма с лай-кой.— Па-па, от-крой ма-ши-ну. / Жукова Н. С. Букварь: учебное пособие. 2012 г. (Стр. 43)

Answer (score 1):

Из комментария: *вопрос просто в том, можно ли использовать "с" между двумя именами, или там должно быть "и".*
А чего ж нельзя-то? Можно, не запрещается.
Саша (кто?) и Маша (кто?) — однородные подлежащие.
Саша (с кем? Т. п.) с Машей — подлежащее с дополнением (или всё сочетание может являться подлежащим).

**Саша с Дашей** ведут светский образ жизни, у них постоянно собираются гости... [Александра Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают. Т. 1 (2014)]

**Саша с Володей** вломились туда, подхватили его под руки ― он ноги поджимал, кричал ― и поволокли по коридору в комнату, уложили на кровать. [Дина Рубина. На солнечной стороне улицы (1980-2006)]

А **Саша с Олей** мне были очень симпатичны. [Алла Сурикова. Любовь со второго взгляда (2001)]

И **Саша с Ниной** получили по миске с белым хлебом! [Булат Окуджава. Упраздненный театр (1989-1993)]

В Нацкорпусе: [Саша с...](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=0&req=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%20%D1%81&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform)

В правилах Розенталя тоже есть примеры (даже в самом названии).
[Сказуемое при подлежащем типа ***брат с сестрой***](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html)